# Oracle - How to join tables with JSON data?

Tags: sql, json, oracle, join

I want to create a view that needs to select from many tables, one of which is a table with JSON data in it. So let us say it has a definition like this

```
CREATE TABLE    
    PERSON    
    (    
        ID RAW(16) NOT NULL,    
        OBJECT CLOB,    
        CONSTRAINT JSON_DOCUMENTS_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID),    
        CONSTRAINT JSON_DOCUMENTS_JSON CHECK (object IS JSON (STRICT))    
    );
```

And the data in it can be like in this example

```
INSERT INTO person (id, object)    
VALUES (SYS_GUID(),    
        '{"data" : {    
          "FirstName"      : "Adam",    
          "LastName"       : "Doe",    
          "Job"            : "Clerk",    
          "DateOfBirth"    : "01-JAN-1980",    
          "Active"         : true    
         }}');
```

I want to merge it with

```
CREATE TABLE Salary (
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Salary number(10) 
);
```

I did not see an example directly doing this. Basically, let us say I need the salaries of the active people in a flat representation.  Do I need to create a flat view of the JSON table and join with that or use a WITH clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes creating separate view with columns (id, firstname, lastname, job, dob, activestaus) for json data of every Person is good to have in this case. It will be simpler to join salary and new personData view to get the joined result. I don't think there is another way to achieve joining a table with clob json data.